# XNA stopped compiling my model x files

Tags: xna, models, xna-content-pipeline

So I've a 3d game project I'm working on and I'm using 2 model files (SkyBlock.x and AimedBlock.x).

So until now everything was all good and my models files were compiled all okay and I was able to use them within my game. With the latest changes (which I don't know what caused it really) - XNA stopped compiling my model files and instead only outputs files;

- AimedBlockxnb - 1kb
- SkyDome.xnb - 1kb
- SkyDomeTexture.xnb - 1389 kb
- SkyDomeTexture_0.xnb - 419 kb

So I created a test XNA game project and moved all my asset's to new solution content project's and tried compiling them and saw that they're all good.

- AimedBlockxnb - 2kb
- SkyDome.xnb - 13kb
- SkyDomeTexture.xnb - 4097 kb
- SkyDomeTexture_0.xnb - 683 kb

So I guess my main project sucks there but I couldn't came with a solution. I even tried overwriting my game's content project with new game's content project (which was all okay) but it didn't work.

Anybody had similar issues?

Comment: You might try rebuilding the whole solution (Ctrl+Alt+F7 or Build > Rebuild Solution)

Comment: I've tried it a million times - and even more manually deleted my bin/ and obj/ folders.

Comment: That's strange. So after manually deleting the files did not regenerate after rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

When you place content in your XNA project, in the **Properties** window you can pick the **Build Action** as well as how the file should be handled (**Content Importer** and **Content Processor**).

In your case, I expect those three properties were changed, but the defaults clearly work for you. The default for the Build Action is **Compile**, and the defaults for the Content Importer and Processor depend on the file format.

Comment: No my build action's are all properly setup.